# Why do I get multiple predictions lines for my binomial GLM?

Tags: r, plot, glm, predict

My data are masses of offspring in kg, and a column of 1's and 0's to represent whether a mother was in her terminal year or not.

```
Chick Mass        Terminal Effect
   3.4                   0
   3.1                   1
   2.4                   1
   3.6                   0
```

etc..

So I have a model fitted to assess whether mass (in kg) has an effect on mortality (binomial)

```
m10 <-glm(Terminal_Effect~chick_mass, data = cranesData, family = binomial(link="logit"))
summary(m10)

plot(cranesData$Terminal_Effect~cranesData$chick_mass, xlab = "Chick Mass (kg)", ylab = "Probability of Mother Death", pch = 19)
```

When I plot this, there are multiple lines on my plot, is there a way to change this to a single line?

[image: Plot]

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your predictor values before plotting.

using the iris dataset with some variation:

```
set.seed(111)
dat = iris
dat$Species = as.numeric(dat$Species=="setosa")
dat$Petal.Width = dat$Petal.Width + rnorm(nrow(dat))
```

Order the predictor, in this case it is petal.width:

```
dat = dat[order(dat$Petal.Width),]

fit = glm(Species ~ Petal.Width,data=dat,family="binomial")

plot(dat$Species ~ dat$Petal.Width)
lines(dat$Petal.Width,fit$fitted.values,col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Terrific! This worked, thanks. Sometimes it's the really obvious things that get you.